# Customer User Authentication error : AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'user_management.CustomUser'

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am trying to use email for authenication in Django. In other words I am extending django authentication. I followed all the steps and trust me it worked before. Now it stopped working.

## this is model.py

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser,BaseUserManager,PermissionsMixin
    from django.core.mail import send_mail
    from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
    #now=time.strftime('%Y-%M-%D %H:%m:%S.%u%Z')
    import datetime
    from datetime import timedelta

    from django.utils import timezone
    from django.utils.timezone import now


    tomorrow = timezone.now() + timedelta(days=1)
    current_time= timezone.now()

    class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
        def _create_user(self,email,password,is_staff,is_superuser, **extra_fields):

            if not email:
                raise ValueError('The given email must be set')

            email=self.normalize_email(email)
            user= self.model(email=email,
                             is_staff=is_staff,
                             is_active = True,
                             is_superuser =is_superuser,
                             last_login=timezone.now(),
                             date_joined=timezone.now(),
                            **extra_fields)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save(using=self._db)
            return user

        def create_user(self, email,password=None,**extra_fields):
            return self._create_user(email,password,False,False,**extra_fields)

        def create_superuser(self, email,password,**extra_fields):
            return self._create_user(email,password,True,True,**extra_fields)

    class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
        username =models.CharField(max_length =255, unique = True,blank = True,null= True)
        email =models.EmailField(blank=False, unique =True)
        date_joined  = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=now)
        is_active    = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        is_admin     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_staff     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

        USERNAME_FIELD ='email'
        REQUIRED_FIELD =['user_name','date_joined']

        objects=CustomUserManager()

        class Meta:
            verbose_name=_('user')
            verbose_name_plural=_('users')

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return "/user/%s" %urlquote(self.email)

        def get_full_name(self):

            a=UserProfile.objects.get(email_id=self.id)
            self.first_name=a.first_name
            self.last_name= a.last_name
            if not self.first_name and not self.last_name:
                full_name =self.email
            else:
                full_name = '%s %s' %(self.first_name,self.last_name)
            return full_name.strip()

        def get_short_name(self):
            self.first_name='a'
            return self.first_name

        def email_user(self,subject,message,from_email=None):
            send_mail(subject,message,from_email,[self.email])


            #code

    class UserProfile(models.Model):

        email = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,unique =True,primary_key=True)
        first_name=models.CharField(max_length =256, blank = True)
        last_name=models.CharField(max_length =256, blank = True)
        activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=40,blank=True)
        gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True,blank=True,choices=(
            ('male', 'Male'),
            ('female', 'Female'),))
        date_of_birth=models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
        key_expires = models.DateTimeField(default=tomorrow)

        def __str__(self):
            full_name = '%s %s' %(self.first_name,self.last_name)
            return full_name

        class Meta:
            verbose_name=u'User profile'
            verbose_name_plural=u'User profiles'

        models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, related_name='Userprofile')

    class UserAddress(models.Model):
        address_contact=models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=False)
        address_line1=models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=False)
        address_line2=models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True)
        land_mark=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
        city=models.CharField(max_length=140,blank=False)
        state=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
        pin_code = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False)
        mobile_no=models.CharField(max_length=13,blank=True)
        last_shipped_flag=models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_active_flag=models.BooleanField(default=True)
        is_primary=models.BooleanField(default=False)
        creation_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,editable=False,blank=False,null=True)
        updation_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,editable=False,blank=False,null=True)
        email=models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)


        def __str__(self):
            return self.address_contact


        class Meta:
            verbose_name=u'User Address'
            verbose_name_plural=u'User Addresses'
```

## this is manager.py

```
from models import CustomUser

class CustomUserAuth(object):

    def authenticate(self, username = None, password =None):
        try:
            user =CustomUser.objects.get(email=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            user=CustomUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
            if user.is_active:
                return user
            return None
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

I have included following lines in my settings.py file

```
    AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user_management.CustomUser'

    AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('user_management.manager.CustomUserAuth',)
```

now for troubleshooting I ran python manage.py shell and import the form

CustomUserCreationForm and passed the data to it and tried to save it. 
I got the same error

error trace back

```
 

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 110, in save
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 459, in save
        if self.errors:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 175, in errors
        self.full_clean()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 386, in full_clean
        self._post_clean()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 413, in _post_clean
        self.instance.full_clean(exclude=exclude, validate_unique=False)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1235, in full_clean
        self.clean()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 349, in clean
        self.email = self.__class__.objects.normalize_email(self.email)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 198, in __get__
        cls._meta.swapped,
    AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'user_management.CustomUser'
```

There is much info about the following error. I tried to google but I found one bug in django 1.5  for which ticket is closed. Few smart people said I used get_user_model but those information is incomplete.

Please help

Comment: If your only purpose of creating a custom User model is to use email in authentication, i'll suggest you should change the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` instead of using a custom user model. Please refer to this question if you want email login: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332190/django-login-with-email

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is relevant or not but are you getting the UserProfile correctly in your def get_full_name(self):  Here you have:

```
a=UserProfile.objects.get(email_id=self.id)
```

however I don't see email_id specified in your Class UserProfile.  You have email specified and the class is sub-classed from models.Model which, by default, I would expect to only have an id column not email_id unless you have changed it.

Just a thought.

Comment: I fixed it myself. I changed it get_user_model from CustomUser in forms.py for CustomUserCreationForm
Class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()

Comment: @user3698694 if you found an accurate fix, please add it as an answer or remove the question if you don't think it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

In Django, the `get_user_model()` function is used to retrieve the user model that is currently active in the Django project. This function returns the user model that is specified in the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting.

When working with forms in Django, particularly when creating a custom user creation form, it is important to ensure that you reference the correct user model. By default, Django uses the built-in `User` model, but in some cases, you may have a custom user model defined in your project.

In your case, you made a change in `forms.py` for the `CustomUserCreationForm` class. You updated the model attribute in the `Meta` class of the form to use `get_user_model()` instead of **explicitly** specifying `CustomUser`.

This change ensures that the form uses the active user model defined in the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting. By using `get_user_model()`, you make your code more flexible and avoid hard-coding the user model, allowing it to work correctly with the default user model or any custom user model you have defined in your project.