# Creating Django User object for each user in backend

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a custom backend for authenticating users by their email address instead of username. I've already written a custom User model that inherits from `AbstractUser`:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        _('email address'),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        primary_key=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 150 characters of fewer. Must be a valid email address.'),
        error_messages={
            'unique':_("A user with that email address already exists."),
        },
    )
```

As you can see, I've made the email-field unique, and also, a primary key.

I'm following the docs for how to write the backend, and I've read this:

> The Django admin is tightly coupled to the Django User object. The
>   best way to deal with this is to create a Django User object for each
>   user that exists for your backend (e.g., in your LDAP directory, your
>   external SQL database, etc.) You can either write a script to do this
>   in advance, or your authenticate method can do it the first time a
>   user logs in.

It says that I should create a Django User object (which I'm guessing is the default User object django.contrib.auth.models.User) for each **user in my backend**.

Question 1: If a backend is a class that implements `get_user(user_id)` and `authenticate(request, **credentials)` (this is said in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend)), how can a backend contain users? What is meant by "**user in my backend**"?

Question 2: Do I really have to create a normal Django User object, if my cutsom user objects are subclasses of `AbstractUser`? They're pretty much identical to `django.contrib.auth.models.User`, except that the email-field is primary key and unique.

Comment: You need just a custom authentication backend, not a whole model. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/37332393/7654934.

Comment: The `email` field should definitely be unique if you want to use it to log-in, but you may want to rethink using it as the `primary_key`. This might make it tricky for users to change email address.

Comment: The default authentication backend supports a custom user model with `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'`. I would do that, and then there's no need for a custom authentication backend.

Comment: Alasdair, isn't the example in the docs several orders of magnitude more difficult than the previous question that Ivanov linked to?

Comment: I probably shouldn't have linked to [that example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example), I've removed it from my answer now. That example is using `AbstractBaseUser`, not `BaseUser`, so more code is required. See [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43209322/113962) answer from the question @N.Ivanov linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'` for your custom model, then you shouldn't have to write a custom authentication backend. The default [`ModelBackend`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend) will handle logging in with email.

When Django talks about users in your backend, it means the LDAP directory or external database that contains those uses, not your [backend class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.backends) that accesses these. If you have a custom user model then the `get_user` model should return that, and not the `User` model. However, as I said already, it sounds like it isn't actually necessary for you to write your own authentication backend.