# Django user model username (unique=False)

Tags: python, django

I have seen many of the solution but none of it seems to be answering the question.

My user model is using AbstractUser right now. Is there a way to make username(unique = False)

Since i wanted to allow user to ba able to have duplication of same username, as the login im am using is by email address and password

Below is the code that i tried but doesnt work.

Code:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=False)
```

error:

`customuser.MyUser: (auth.E003) 'MyUser.username' must be unique because it is named as the 'USERNAME_FI ELD'`

Comment: Can this help with what you're trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332190/django-login-with-email?

Comment: @bonidjukic I already can login using email. I just need to make username unique = false. Thats it

Comment: The code you have should work. Have you updated your settings to instruct Django to use your custom `User` model?

Comment: `customuser.MyUser: (auth.E003) 'MyUser.username' must be unique because it is named as the 'USERNAME_FI
ELD'.` This is the error i get

Comment: You should add that error to your question, that would make it much more clear.

Answer (score 3):

A non-unique username field is allowed if you use a custom authentication backend that can support it.

If you want to use django's default authentication backend you cannot make username non unique.

You will have to implement a class with get_user(user_id) and authenticate(request, **credentials) methods for a custom backend.

You can read it in the documentation here. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-custom-user-model

Answer (score 2):

Try to specify email as username field with `USERNAME_FIELD` attribute:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Comment: then the unique=False would ruin the whole validation of unique email

Comment: email is a must to be unique, Just wanted to change username unique into false.

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Comment: Please explain a little about your answer.

Comment: @MehrdadPedramfar I don't know about his code so I just want give some info related to his code and I don't want to add something additional in it.....       And he is inheriting AbstractUser class so, that username field will directly make an impact on the Django username field.... This is it

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, if a custom user class is used and with the authentication backend from Django itself:

1. Create a custom user class based on the Abstract User class:

   ```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

    class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
        username = models.CharField(_("username"), max_length=254, unique=False)
        email = models.EmailField(_("email"), max_length=254, unique=True)

        USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["username"]

        objects = CustomUserManager()

        def __str__(self):
          return self.username
   ```
2. Create a Custom User Manager class, as described in: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-a-manager-for-a-custom-user-model
3. Update the SQL database configuration by running in bash:

   ```
    manage.py makemigrations
    manage.py migrate
   ```

The username field now should be recognised as non-unique, while the email is the unique key identifier.

Hope this helps!

MK.