# user authenticate is not working Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models, django-users

user is not getting authenticated when i try to login.

this my register code

```
def register(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST["name"]
    email =  request.POST["email"]
    password = request.POST["password"]
    password2 = request.POST["password2"]

    try:
        if password2 != password:
            messages.error(request, "password did'nt match")
        elif User.objects.get(email=email):
            messages.error(request, "user already exists")
    except: 
        if email and username:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, "user created")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Looks like user already exists")

return render(request, 'register.html', {})
```

this if my login code if i am using user.object.get for email and check_password for password it,s working but when i am using authenticate it,s not working . printing authenticate is returning None

```
def login(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST["email"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        print email
        print password
        try:
            user = authenticate(email=email , password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)                    
                return redirect('dashbord')
            else:
                messages.error(request, "password yesn't match")

        except:

            messages.error(request, "login fail plz check ur password or email again")


    return render(request, 'login.html', {})
```

Comment: Your `elif User.objects.get(email=email):` will raise an error in case the `User` does not yet exists.

Comment: Did you configure Django to authenticate over email? The doc is showing that you should authenticate with args username and password, not email and password.

(Edit : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users -> By default it's username and password, if "PermissionDenied" is raised during the authentication process, the value returned by the function is None.)

Comment: Right. You can login using only username and password by default.

Comment: This comment has NOTHING to do with a solution to your problem since there is already valid things to try in the above comments, but please check the syntax (`did'nt,yesn't, plz`) in your error messages, this is getting out of hand.

Comment: The correct contraction for yes+not is "y'ain't", e.g., "Oh hell naw, y'ain't put in the correct password."

Comment: @T.Nel most of website these days use email to register and login. so what should i do to Authenticate using email ? do i have to change in default's ? if yes how do i do it ?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i know that,s why i have putted it inside  " try: " there

Comment: @NeerajJoon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332190/django-login-with-email for authenticating on user's email.
I posted an answer if your question is now solved.

Comment: @NeerajJoon It's generally a bad behavior not to be precise about the exception you want to catch. I recommand you to replace `except:` by `except ObjectDoesNotExist:` . You'll have to do `from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, you are using default authentication system, but you authenticate with this line :

`user = authenticate(email=email , password=password)`

The fix, according to your question, is :


    <strike>`email = request.POST["email"]`</strike>

```
username = request.POST["name"]
user = authenticate(username=username , password=password)
```

By default, django log with username, not with email (Cf : [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users) ).

For your question in the comment, it is a duplicate of [Django - Login with Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332190/django-login-with-email).
I invite you to find your solution in the accepted answer.