# Django custom authentication back-end doesn't work

Tags: python, django

I want my Django project to authenticate users with their email instead of their user-name. I followed [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332190/django-login-with-email), but it doesn't work.

This is my `EmailBackend`

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwars):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user

        return None
```

I have added `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['GeneralApp.utils.EmailBackend']` to **settings.py** and, when it is commented, I can login using user-name, and when I uncomment it, I cannot login anymore. I have traced out that the code of `GeneralApp.utils.EmailBackend.authenticate()` is never executed, but I know Django can locate the class because I have misspelled it intentionally and I get an error, and when I correct the typo, no exception is raised. I also know that the default authentication backend was effectively override because I cannot neither login with user-name. I have this same solution working perfectly in another project so I cannot understand why the custom authentication code is never executed when the class is perfectly located with `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` set to it.

Comment: Which version of django you are using?. Have you getting any error or exception while using custom backend?

Comment: It's Djando 2.1. No exception at all

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Ok, I have tried this before with Django 2.0.5, but it stopped working with Django 2.1. I researched [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/) and found that custom authentication backend class now expects parameter **request** in method **authenticate**. So the final code for Django 2.1 is:

```
class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwars):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user

        return None
```

Comment: A backend should run the default password hasher once and also check for inactive users. This backend should not be used in production.

Answer (score 5):

**Working in Django 3.x**

Custom Authentication file would look like:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


User = get_user_model()


class EmailAuthBackend(object):
    """It provides the functionality to slide down to email to login,
    instead of just username"""
    def authenticate(self,request,username=None,password=None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=username)
            if user.check_password(password):   #you can also test user.is_active
                return user 
            return None
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self,user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

and in the settings.py we need to put:

```
#Custom Authentication Backend
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'path_to_custom_backend.EmailAuthBackend',
]
```

Comment: A backend should subclass `BaseBackend`,should run the default password hasher once and also check for inactive users.

Comment: check_password method uses the default hasher itself. Thanks for the other suggestions, I will update my answer after verifying other points by my side.

Comment: If `User.DoesNotExist` exception is raised then `user.check_password` is not called.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43209322/6793666) might help you.
Inheriting from a helper class and making a Custom user is a better approach rather than writing your own custom back end.

Answer (score 1):

**Django 2.1 - 4.0**

When creating an authentication backend it is best to follow the example of `ModelBackend` and run the default password hasher.

The following backend will authenticate using emails as well as usernames.

```py
# backends.py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.db.models import Q

UserModel = get_user_model()


class CustomModelBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        if username is None:
            username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD, kwargs.get(UserModel.EMAIL_FIELD))
        if username is None or password is None:
            return
        try:
            user = UserModel._default_manager.get(
                Q(username__exact=username) | Q(email__iexact=username)
            )
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
            # difference between an existing and a nonexistent user (#20760).
            UserModel().set_password(password)
        else:
            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user
```

Be sure to add your backend to `settings.py`

```py
# settings.py

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ["path.to.backends.CustomModelBackend"]
```