# Django returns session id but doesn't authenticate user

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-users, django-sessions, django-auth-models

I have the following code that sends requests to check JWT token, then authorize user and return authorized session with Access token, Refresh Token and Session ID.

```
@csrf_exempt
def new_login_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    def convert_data(req):
        data = {
            "email": req.data['username'],
            "password": req.data['password'],
        }
        try:
            data["language"] = request.LANGUAGE_CODE
        except:
            data["language"] = request.POST.get('language', 'en')
        return data

    if request.user.is_authenticated and not request.META.get('HTTP_X_AVOID_COOKIES'):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET.get(KEY_NEXT, '/'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        request_data = convert_data(request)

        # request to Accounts API to check if user exists
        response = send_service_request(EnumAuthUrls.sign_in.value,
                                        json_data=request_data,
                                        original_response=True)

        if isinstance(response, dict):
            return JsonResponse(response)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            tok_ac = response.headers.get(HEADER_ACCESS_KEY)
            tok_ref = response.headers.get(HEADER_REFRESH_KEY)

            # checking JWT token
            user = ApiAuthenticationBackend().authenticate(request, tok_ac)

            # creates session
            data = login_session(request, response, user)

            data['user_id'] = request.user.id
            data['account_id'] = request.user.profile.account_id
            data['balance'] = request.user.balance
            if request.META.get('HTTP_X_AVOID_COOKIES'):
                return JsonResponse(data)

            response = AuthResponse(
                data=data,
                ssid=request.session.session_key,
                access_token=tok_ac,
                refresh_token=tok_ref,
            )

            return response

        else:
            return ErrorApiResponse(response.json())

    service = urllib.parse.quote_plus(request.build_absolute_uri())
    return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.ACCOUNTS_URL + f'login/?service={service}')
```

Here's the code of `login_session` fucntion:

```
def login_session(request: HttpRequest, response: HttpResponse, user):
    request.user = user
    request.session.create()
    base_data = response.json().get(KEY_DATA)
    return request.user.serialize(request, base_data, token=True)
```

And here's the class `AuthResponse` that is eventually based on `HttpResponse`:

```
class AuthResponse(SuccessResponse):
    def __init__(self, data={}, ssid='', access_token: str = '', refresh_token: str = '', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(data, **kwargs)
        if ssid:
            logger.debug(f'Setting {settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME}: {ssid}')
            self.set_cookie(key=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME,
                            value=ssid)
        if access_token:
            self.set_cookie(key=settings.ACCESS_KEY_COOKIE_NAME,
                            value=access_token)
        if refresh_token:
            self.set_cookie(key=settings.REFRESH_KEY_COOKIE_NAME,
                            value=refresh_token)
```

The problem is that looks everything good on the browser side, I get all needed cookies (access token, refresh token and session id) however after trying logging in I get redirected to the main page.

There was problem in the beginning with setting cookies, but then I found out that I should not use `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` if it's local. Thus all cookies came up without problem but it didn't resolve situation with authorization.

While setting cookies with `self.set_cookie()` I tried to use `secure=True`, `samesite='Lax'`, `httponly=True`, and all other parameters but it didn't help.

Does anyone knows what else I can try in order to fix it?

Comment: It seems your haven't added you custom Authentication backend to the settings.py. 
similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51870788/django-custom-authentication-back-end-doesnt-work

Comment: I have in `settings.py` following settings:
`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ("applications.authentication.backends.ApiAuthenticationBackend",)`

And this is where actually I'm checking the JWT token...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found what was wrong!

There was middleware that supposed to check token from another service. However it was checking old token, instead of new one.

So once I changed it and started to check new token - it was working just fine.

So if there's no other solutions, make sure you have checked middleware or other code where it could affect on whole system.