# Using Email as login in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am not able to login in django with correct password and email. here is my code.

backends.py

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class Emailbackend(object):

        def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=username)
            except User.MultipleObjectsReturned:
                user = User.objects.filter(email=username).order_by('id').first()
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return None
            if getattr(user, 'is_active') and user.check_password(password):
                return user
            return None

        def get_user(self, user_id):
            try:
                User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return None
```

Settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'users.backends.Emailbackend',
)
```

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive. but im entering correct password

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - Login with Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332190/django-login-with-email)

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332190/django-login-with-email

Comment: not working im using django 2.1

Comment: in console it is printing like this : [26/Dec/2018 12:21:36] "POST /login/?next=/company/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3152

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, `authenticate` method expects an argument `request` should be passed. So you need to declare your Backend like this:

```
class Emailbackend(object):

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
        # rest of the code
```

Reference can be found [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L68).

Answer (score 0):

first check the value of `user` in authenticate method try block. If it get correct result then check following block what `user` value return.

```
if getattr(user, 'is_active') and user.check_password(password):
    return user
```

If it doesn't work then go to your database and check is your password hash value available or not.

Try these link
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332190/django-login-with-email) [link2](https://medium.com/@ramykhuffash/django-authentication-with-just-an-email-and-password-no-username-required-33e47976b517)

Comment: It is not going inside Try

Comment: check which block will execute and what value you get?

Comment: It is also not going inside def authenticate