# Django Authentication Login returns nothing

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm trying to log users in with django authenticate. It returns nothing even when the email and password are correct. It just reloads the page and doesn't do anything. I have checked and the email and password I used are stored in the database, so the account exist but login doesn't do anything. I am using django 2.

**Views.py**

```
def signup(request):
 if request.method == "POST":
    firstname = request.POST.get('firstname')
    lastname = request.POST.get('lastname')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    passwordagain = request.POST.get('passwordagain')
    areacode = request.POST.get('areacode')
    number = request.POST.get('number')
    userdetails = CustomUser(firstname=firstname,lastname=lastname,email=email,password=password, areacode=areacode, number=number)
    userdetails.save()
    return render(request, 'main/accountconfirmationpage.html')
else:
    return render(request,'main/signup.html')



def login(request):
    email=request.POST.get('email')
    password=request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return render(request,'main/dashboard.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'main/login.html')



from django.db import models
```

**Models.py**

```
# Create your models here.
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    areacode = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your signup. You are not storing password properly in `signup` view.

```
userdetails = CustomUser(firstname=firstname,lastname=lastname,email=email,password=password, areacode=areacode, number=number)  # <-- Here
userdetails.save()
```

As you are not storing the password properly(currently it is being stored as plaintext rather than hashed), that is why `authenticate` function is not able to get the user.

So, you need to set password like this:

```
userdetails = CustomUser(firstname=firstname,lastname=lastname,email=email, areacode=areacode, number=number)
userdetails.set_password(password)
userdetails.save()
```

For more details, please check here on [set_password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password) function.

Comment: I actually tried this before I posted this question, it didn't work. It says 'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'set_password'. I even tried changing CustomUser to django's User still no luck.

Comment: to avail `set_password`, you need to subclass your CustomUser from [AbstractBaseUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser) or [AbstractUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser). Hope it helps @Styxin

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the Django User Model like this:

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

#this will extend User model with your own model
class CustomUser(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      # all the other fields you mentioned except areacode and number
      # are already in User model so don't need to add them here
      areacode = models.CharField(max_length=4)
      number = models.CharField(max_length=30)

# Below code will hook the create_custom_user and save_custom_user methods
# to the User model, whenever a save event occurs

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_custom_user(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
       CustomeUser.objects.create(user=instance)   

@receiver(post_save, sender=User):
def save_custom_user(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.customeuser.save()
```

Now you can create the user with your `CustomModel` in views like this:

**Views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def signup(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
      # I would suggest to use django forms 
      # instead of getting the values directly from request.POST  
      user = User(firstname=firstname, lastname=lastname, email=email)
      user.customuser.areacode = areacode
      user.customuser.number = number
      user.set_password(password)
      user.save()
      # rest of the code
```

[doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/) for forms in django

Also for login the user with email instead of username you need to write an authentication backend for that and register it in your `settings.py` take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332190/django-login-with-email)