# What exactly is the parameter 'username' in authenticate function django?

Tags: django

From [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) about `django.contrib.auth.authenticate` function, we find -

> Use authenticate() to verify a set of credentials. It takes credentials as keyword arguments, **username and password** for the default case, checks them against each authentication backend, and returns a User object if the credentials are valid for a backend.

Now, my question is what do they mean by username?

- Is it the name of the column of a model?
- Or is it a primary key to a model?

Actually, I have been sending email as a username because I wanted to check credentials based on email (primary key) rather than username (whatever it means) but it didn't work... But I named one of a column of my model to *username* but it still didn't work... So, I wonder what do they mean by *username* exactly.

My code that didn't work -

```
email = request.POST['email']
#email = request.POST['username'] Changed email column-name to username but didn't work!
password = request.POST['password']
user = authenticate(request, username=email, password=password)
print (user) ## None
```

Answer (score 1):

The default UserModel contains the `username` Attribute (column of the model), this is used to identify the user in the authentication backend. You have two possibilities:

- Create a new UserModel without the username Attribute to use the email to authenticate (You have to create a new Authentication Backend)
- Just change the authentication backend to authenticate with the email or both and keep the username Attribute

To replace the username with the email:
https://medium.com/@ramykhuffash/django-authentication-with-just-an-email-and-password-no-username-required-33e47976b517 
[Django - Login with Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332190/django-login-with-email)

If you just want to change the authentication backend, to authenticate with the email: 
[Django - Login with Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332190/django-login-with-email)

P.S. The `username` argument of the `authenticate` function shouldn't be renamed, even if you use the `email` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the link. And can you answer the question more specifically?

Comment: I hope I answered your questions.